# Rocketeer. How can I execute commands on different servers after deploying?

Tags: php, laravel

I have several servers - backend, frontend and api.
To deploy the code on the servers I use Rocketeer.

I use multiple servers for one connection:

```
'connections' => array(
    'production' => array(
        'servers' => array(
            array(
                'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', // backend
                'username' => 'admin',
                'password' => 'xxxxxx',
                'key' => '',
                'keyphrase' => '',
            ),
            array(
                'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', // api
                'username' => 'admin',
                'password' => 'xxxxxx',
                'key' => '',
                'keyphrase' => '',
            ),
            array(
                'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', // frontend
                'username' => 'admin',
                'password' => 'xxxxxx',
                'key' => '',
                'keyphrase' => '',
            ),          
        ),
    ),
).
```

For each server performs its tasks.

To determine the current connection, I use the following code in hooks.php

```
$connection = $task->getConnection();
$server = $connection->connections->getServer();
$credentials = $connection->connections->getServerCredentials($connection->connections->getConnection(), $server);

switch($credentials['host']){
    case 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx':
        $task->runForCurrentRelease('...');
        break;
}
```

The data are uploaded to servers sequentially.

After deploying to last server I can't execute command on previous servers.

How can I execute commands on different servers after deploying? (for example: restart nginx, restart memcached etc.)

Comment: You can use this to determine the current connection: var_dump($task->getConnection()->getName());

Comment: I just saw on Laracasts, a tool called envoyer.io to automate deployments.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for: http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu/#/docs/docs/II-Concepts/Events

You should be able to create your own listener for each set of commands.